# How can I summarize several timesteps in R?

Tags: r, average, heatmap, summarize

I want to draw a heat map showing the operating period of a ventilation system over the year. Since my dataset has 1minute-timesteps, I need to summarize the values to hourly-timesteps (1440 values on the y-axis result in a too small resolution). So I am looking for a command to average the first 60 values, the next 60 and so on...

`dput(head(mydate,20))
structure(list(date = structure(c(1498373340, 1498373400, 1498373460, 
1498373520, 1498373580, 1498373640, 1498373700, 1498373760, 1498373820, 
1498373880, 1498373940, 1498374000, 1498374060, 1498374120, 1498374180, 
1498374240, 1498374300, 1498374360, 1498374420, 1498374480), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), DS.ZV_SB = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Despite you're not marked as new user, you seems quite new here, so welcome to SO! Could you add an excerpt of your data? You can try `dput(head(your_data_here,20))`, that is going to give an output like `structure(...` and you can post it (the output) here *editing the question*. It's going to give us your first 20 rows of data to make answers more precise. If you cannot post your data, please add some fake data similar to yours.

Comment: Thanks! I solved my issue like this:  
`openair::timeAverage(mydate, avg.time = "hour")`

as a result, I get hourly values 
`date                DS.ZV_SB
  <dttm>                 <dbl>
1 2017-06-25 08:00:00        0
2 2017-06-25 09:00:00        0
3 2017-06-25 10:00:00        0
4 2017-06-25 11:00:00        0
5 2017-06-25 12:00:00        0
6 2017-06-25 13:00:00        0`